# Where is the FocusManager in a uwp xaml applications?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I'm trying to solve a problem in a xaml / uwp application. Most of the suggestions I'm finding refer to a class called FocusManager, which appears to be a property of many controls and containers.

Unfortunately, whenever I try to use it, I find that there is no such property available in my application on any of my controls, including Page, UserControl, StackPanel, etc.

I'm confused as to why this is.

How do I access this class in my application? Or, is there a different way to change the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this `FocusManager` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager). It is a helper class that enables global management of focus actions and events across all elements in an application, but not a property of the control or page. And the following is demo code that could test.

```
private void Page_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
   {
      // Mimic Shift+Tab when user hits up arrow key.
      FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous);
   }
   else if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
   {
      // Mimic Tab when user hits down arrow key.
      FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
   }
}
```

Comment: I've been able to set focus on my <Page /> view's Close button using MainPage.xaml.cs OnNavigated() code `this.close.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` or `Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(this.close, FocusState.Programmatic);`. I'd prefer a way to declaratively set this in the xaml markup. Is there a way to do that?  I've tried following samples showing that with things like `xmlns:xi="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Input"` coupled with seemingly deprecated `<StackPanel . . . FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=close}">` syntax but having no luck.

Comment: @myusrn, I suggest you post a new thread for your issue that could make more communities could view the similar

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, created new thread for this matter at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349354/uwp-xaml-declaratively-defining-control-that-has-focus-by-default .