# uwp xaml declaratively defining control that has focus by default

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been able to set focus on my  view's Close button using the following code in the MainPage.xaml.cs OnNavigatedTo() event handler.

```
this.close.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` 
// or 
Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(this.Close, FocusState.Programmatic);`
```

I'd prefer a way to declaratively set this in the xaml markup. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried following samples provided in SO post hits on this subject showing approaches llike the following using FocussedElement, which appears to have been deprecated, and am having no luck.

```
<Page . . . xmlns:xi="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Input">
    <StackPanel . . . FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Close}">
    <!-- or -->
    <Button Name="Close" . . . xi:FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">Close</Button>
```

Comment: There is no way to set the focus status in XAML markup. You might still need to do it in code-behind. May I know why you need to implement in XAML markup?

Comment: because it allows view designers working in markup only to declare which control they want to have focus by default at view startup time vs them having to go into code behind to accomplish it

Comment: It's a good idea. You could submit a feature request in the FeedBack Hub about this and let others vote up for it.